# DataTables - Open all Child Rows on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

At the moment my table has child rows with a toggle to open each row in column 1. (I found this function online for managing the child rows) how can I change this so that child rows are always open so I can get rid of column one. https://jsfiddle.net/6k0bshb6/30/

```
// This function is for displaying data from HTML "data-child-value" tag in the Child Row.
function format(value) {
      return '<div>Hidden Value: ' + value + '</div>';
  }

// This function is for handling Child Rows.
    $('#example').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          var row = dataTable.row(tr);

          if (row.child.isShown()) {
              // This row is already open - close it
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the code below to show all child rows:

```
$("#example").DataTable().rows().every( function () {
    var tr = $(this.node());
    this.child(format(tr.data('child-value'))).show();
    tr.addClass('shown');
});
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k0bshb6/31/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: How to expand/collapse all child rows](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/#regular) for more examples and information.