# Jquery datatable is able to expand/collapse all the rows except the individual row that is already expanded/collapsed before

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am new to Jquery. I have a data table where each individual row can be expanded/collapsed to show the children as dynamic table that contain further rows when the parent row is clicked. My code is working without any hassle when row is clicked individually.

here is the code:

```
//expand or collapse any case

    $(".dataTables_scrollBody").find(".details-control").on("click", function () {

        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            // Open this row
            var td = $(this).parent('td');


            row.child(format(row)).show()
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
```

Here is my format() function:

```
function format(row) {
    //we already stored formatted CKEY info on the formattedCKEY node. So get it from the selected case row
    var formattedCKEY = row.data()[1];
    var cases = $(soapGetResultslist.responseXml).find("formattedCKEY:contains(" + formattedCKEY + ")").prevAll("issue");
    var issuetable = '<table id="IssuesTable" class="stripe nowrap" style="position:relative; top:0px; width:95%;">' +
        '<thead>' +
        '<tr>' +

        '<th>Issue ID</th>' +
        '<th>Subject</th>' +

        '<thead>' +
        '</tr>' + '<tbody>' + '<tr>';

    $.each(cases, function () {

        issuetable = issuetable + '<tr>' + '<td>' + $(this).find("IKEY").text() + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + $(this).find("SUBJECT").text() + '</td>' + '</tr>'
    });

    issuetable = issuetable + '</tbody>' + '</tr>' + '</table>';
    return issuetable;
}
```

In the above function `soapGetResultslist.responseXml` is just xml response.

Now I want to expand/collapse all the rows at once using only one button `+/-` like this:

```
<td style="width:135px;" ><button id="expand-collapse-button" >+/-</button></td>
```

I have added the following jquery code to expand/collapse all at once:

```
// Handle click on "+/-(expand all or collapse all)" 
            $("#expand-collapse-button").click( function() {
             // Expand row details
                table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
             });
```

I am able to expand/collapse all the rows at once only when any one of the rows is not expanded/collapsed individually before.

**For example:**

If a row is expanded individually(let's say the first row) once, then if we try to expand all the rows at once by clicking on the button `+/-`, all the rows will get expanded except the first row (the first row will be collapsed this time against the expectations).

can anybody share their thoughts/code on how to overcome this situation?

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because you're executing an event 'click' on each row.
If a row it was already expanded, by doing this you'll collapse it again.

Maybe these links could help you

[jQuery DataTables: How to expand/collapse all child rows](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-how-to-expand-collapse-all-child-rows/#regular)

[DataTables - Open all Child Rows on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395508/datatables-open-all-child-rows-on-page-load/37398851#37398851)

Answer (score 0):

You have it documented in your code `// This row is already open - close it` So that is what it will do when you trigger the click event.

One possible implementation:

Add a class to the entire table when expanded by the `+/-` button.

In your if statement you could then check whether the table has class "expanded" or not. If it does then do not collapse any expanded rows.

And likewise if all rows are expanded but one, check if table has class "expanded" if not then collapse all rows and keep current collapsed rows collapsed.

```
//EXPAND ALL ROWS BUTTON
$("#expand-collapse-button").click( function() {
    // Expand row details

    if($('#IssuesTable').hasClass('expanded')){
       $('#IssuesTable').removeClass('expanded');
    }else{
        $('#IssuesTable').addClass('expanded');
    }

    table.rows(':not(.parent)').nodes().to$().find('td:first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

Then target that in your event listener.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry for my delayed response. In my case `IssuesTable` is a dynamic table. Could you please elaborate your answer. I am little confused.